# What is this plant with large broad serrated leaves?

Tags: identification

[image: top view of plant]
[image: side profile view]

This came growing out of a seed pack of *Lavandula hidcote blue* which it obviously isn't. Now I'm kinda puzzled as to what on earth I'm carefully nurturing.

I reside in Singapore, so temperatures are high all year around in the 20s to 30s as is the humidity here. This plant is seriously killing it at the whole growing-big-thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely solanaceous.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae

I would guess from there it's either a Brugmansia, Datura, or an Eggplant.

The leaf shape, arrangement, and the way the new leaves are forming, as well as the growth habit, are consistent with any of these three families. You can probably help distinguish between the three by crumpling a leaf and smelling it.  Datura and Brugmansia have strong distinctive bitter smells I don't really know how to describe it.  I don't believe that eggplant has much of an odor but I will have to check when I get home today.

The more I look at your photo the more I believe is is a brugmansia from the way new leaves are emerging from the node between the leaf and stem, but you will find out eventually as it grows more and flowers.

Comment: Thanks! What sort of smell should I be expecting for each of the three? I also really hope I don't accidentally poison myself.

Comment: So don't inhale ^_^! Just kidding, unless you eat it, simply smelling at a crushed leaf isn't dangerous. Wash your hands afterwards, though.

Comment: You won't poison yourself by smelling it.  Just don't eat any part of the plant unless it's an eggplant.

Comment: I think you're right about the brugmansia! I googled about a bit more and I learnt that they can take levels of fertilizer that would kill most plants. I accidentally double dosed some of my containers and the other plants are struggling, but this one is fine with just a bit of burn on the leaves (visible in the picture)